# How can I track how long some .exe files stayed open

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to track the time I spend when I'm working on unity. For personal use, I want to know how much time I spent today in total. I tried some of the time tracking programs like ManicTime but these programs only track the time of active tasks.If I open unity and switch to chrome to search something about Unity,the time tracker stops for Unity. But since what I'm doing in chrome is related to my Unity project, the time I spent on chrome while unity is open should still be tracked and added to my Unity time. Is there time tracking program which tracks the time of tasks even when they are inactive?

Comment: If this question has anything to do with Unity, where is your timing code?

Comment: Sorry if my tag choice was wrong.I added unity tag in case if there is an in-built feature of unity engine that could be used in the way I explained in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Steam, you could add the program as non-steam games and then when they are "played" it should track their time I believe, so long as you start them through Steam.

Comment: I will try that.Thanks